# periodically executing a function in thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I found a solution for executing a function periodically every N seconds.

```
import threading;

def do_every (interval, worker_func, iterations = 0):
  if iterations != 1:
    threading.Timer (
      interval,
      do_every, [interval, worker_func, 0 if iterations == 0 else iterations-1]
    ).start ();

  worker_func ();

def print_hw ():
  print "hello world";

def print_so ():
  print "stackoverflow"


# call print_so every second, 5 times total
do_every (1, print_so, 5);

# call print_hw two times per second, forever
do_every (0.5, print_hw);
```

When we execute this code it start print "hello world" and "stackoverflow" at the moment execution (at time=0 seconds). What is the possible way to make it printat time=1 second and time=0.5 seconds (not starting at time=0 seconds) without using time.sleep

Answer (score 1):

I would be really hesitant to spawn a new `Timer` every single time. `Timer` extends `Thread`, and no one wants to start a new thread every few seconds.

If we look at the source code for Python, we can provide our own implementation for the `Timer` class. I don't know Python, so there may be a way to extend the class instead of basically copying all of its code.

The `Timer` class uses an `Event` (also in the `threading` module), to wait the specified amount of time.

```python
import threading;
from threading import Thread;
from threading import Event;

#Extended from a class written by Itamar Shtull-Trauring
class MultiTimer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, count = 0, args=None, kwargs=None):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.args = args if args is not None else []
        self.kwargs = kwargs if kwargs is not None else {}
        self.finished = Event()
        self.count = count
        self.infinite = count == 0

    def cancel(self):
        """Stop the timer if it hasn't finished yet."""
        self.finished.set()

    def run(self):
        while not self.finished.is_set():
            self.finished.wait(self.interval)
            if not self.finished.is_set():
                self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
                self.decrementCount()

    def decrementCount(self):
        if not self.infinite:
            self.count -= 1
            if self.count == 0:
                self.finished.set()

def hello():
    print "hello, world"

#prints "hello, world" 3 times, at time = 2, 4, 6
t = MultiTimer(2.0, hello, 3)
t.start();

#never stops printing "hello, world" every 2 seconds
u = MultiTimer(2.0, hello)
u.start();
```

Comment: "Duration" is a much better variable name than "count", for the record. I'll hold off editing the answer, as I'm sure there's a better name than `MultiTimer` as well.